# Keycloak Cookie Not Found Error when behind a Web Proxy

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to have users access Keycloak from a different hostname through a proxy.  Instead of the actual AWS hostname `aws.exampleurl.com:8080` I have a proxy which routes all traffic from `example.hostname.com/auth` to the AWS url.  I am able to access the Keycloak welcome screen and kick off the administrator login (with failed CSS loads which I assume is due to the same issue but I'm not sure), but when I input a set of credentials I am told that there was no cookie found.  I have the cookies set to allow all in my browser (Brave).

I have set the `HOSTNAME_URL` env var to example.hostname.com/auth, tried using a mixture of the `HOSTNAME` and `HOSTNAME_PATH` env vars.  I have tried setting `HOSTNAME_STRICT` to false, but to no luck.  I've tried restarting the service and restarting the database I have running with Keycloak but these changes have also not worked.

Any ideas on how to get this running correctly would be amazing.  Let me know if more info is needed to reproduce.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy) about how to configure a reverse proxy? Not loading CSS usually is an indicator that you're doing something wrong here. Have you checked which files your browser tries to load? That should give you a hint what you're doing wrong :)

Comment: Yeah I have read the documentation on that page.  I've tried playing around with those 4 environment variables on the documentation page.



The usual issue with the css loads is that the requests are being made to `example.hostname.com/auth/auth/FILE` rather than to `example.hostname.com/auth/FILE`.  But I'm not sure why.